# Playing sounds and using buttons with raspberry pi

Tags: python, button, audio, raspberry-pi, mp3

I am trying to complete the project described in this link  https://learn.adafruit.com/playing-sounds-and-using-buttons-with-raspberry-pi/code.
***Please read instructions to get caught up***
My Raspberry Pi is running.
My breadboard is wired correctly with the correct components.
When typing in "sudo python raspi-audio-button.py" and subsequently push some of the buttons I get one of two responses.
 1.) Long line of error descriptions, from what I can tell it says its having trouble retrieving the mp3 files and connecting to the "jack" (speaker?).
2.)no response at all

I have the 3 mp3 files in the "pi" folder next to "raspi-audio-button.py" (which I created with the text editor "nano"). I have followed the instructions and do not know the problem. Please help!

Comment: Please provide the detailed output of the program you're running. I'd also recommend manually a `mpg123` command to see if you can hear what you're supposed to.

Comment: #!/user/bin/env python

import os
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q Middle C.mp3 &')

    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q Middle G.mp3 &')
    
    if (GPIO.input(25) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q +1 C.mp3 &')

    sleep(0.1);

Comment: Posted Above  Could I email you the txt file?  @LeoCavaille

Comment: please edit your post with your program correctly formatted instead and also have you tried to run the `mpg123` command manually in a shell on the raspberry pi?

Comment: I have the alsa drivers installed and the mpg123 MP3 player installed @LeoCavaille

Comment: give me your email and ill send you the txt file, i cant format it correctly in this thing @LeoCavaille

Comment: If you really don't want to use the proper the syntax like everyone else... you can use something like pastebin.com. I am not a masochist, I won't post my email here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to insult you or offend you in any way. I have fixed the problems with my program, I forgot to install the audio drivers. The problem I am having now is when I run the program and then press a button in the terminal it says " cannot open +1 C.mp3: File access error. (code 22) @LeoCavaille. Id like to repeat myself in saying that I am sorry for offending you in any way. I greatly appreciate your help and will make sure my etiquette is appropriate. :)